# How to zoom or shrink the size of ggplot or simple plot in Rmarkdown output?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, r-markdown

I know one way is to specify fig.height and fig.width in the code chunks, but I'd like to keep the default display aspect ratio of the plot.

Is there any option that can control the output size of a plot (like default value 1 stands for the default size and value 2 stands for double size)?

Comment: Not in that way. Note that your perceived "default display aspect ratio" might be based on several things that have no meaning in an Rmd file, such as your screen size, dimensions of the RStudio application (if you are using it) or the dimensions of the `dev` plot (if not RStudio). The "default display aspect ratio" in an Rmd file is defined by the defaults of `rmarkdown`, using the two variables you don't want to change. If you want to change the dimensions of the image but keep the ratio, use some algebra to translate the defaults.

Comment: The option `out.width` might help you scaling your plots and keeping the aspect ratio (`out.width='50%'` to scale a plot down 50%).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `opts.label` option to create lists of options for a chunk. For an example, there are three pairs of `fig.height` and `fig.width` defined by `opts_template$set` and then called in a chunk option.  See the example .Rmd file below.

````
---
title: How to zoom or shrink the size of ggplot or simple plot in Rmarkdown
output: html_document
---

Use option templates, see `?opts_template` for more details.  An example
follows.  There will be three 

```{r setup, include = FALSE, cache = FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)
opts_template$set(figure1 = list(fig.height = 4, fig.width = 4),
                  figure2 = list(fig.height = 2, fig.width = 4),
                  figure3 = list(fig.height = 5, fig.widht = 3)) 
```

The default graphic to show is build here

```{r ourgraphic}
g <- ggplot(mpg) + aes(x = model, y = cty) + geom_boxplot()
```

Use the `opts.label` option to set the figures.  `figure1` is here:
```{r opts.label = "figure1"}
g
```

Now, `figure3`,
```{r opts.label = "figure3"}
g
```

and lastly `figure2`.
```{r opts.label = "figure2"}
g
```
````

Comment: For a list of possible options of code chunks (and `opts_template$set`) see https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#chunk_options